# recorrer un objecto y enviar los datos a firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, object, bucle-for

Hasta ahora tengo el siguiente codigo, me llega un objecto y con un for lo voy recorriendo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          console.log("datos completos ->  " +  data[i].id_expediente);
         //acceder a mis datos de firebase
          this.db.collection("usuarios").doc(this.user.nombre_actuario)
                  .set({
                    [data[i].id_expediente] : JSON.stringify(data[i])
                  })
                  .then(function() {})
                  .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
        }
```

el problema es que solo me guarda el ultimo dato  en firebase, Alguna idea del porque del problema  ?

Comment: Lo que te dicen es cierto, es debido a que estas usando el método equivocado. Por otra parte, te sugeriría que no hagas las peticiones dentro del ciclo, que uses ese ciclo para guardar las peticiones en un arreglo y posteriormente tomar las respuestas con Promise.All es importante que tengas en cuenta la sincronía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que estás usando set, set lo que hace es borrar todo lo que hay en donde quieres guardar y guarda lo que le estás enviando. En su lugar creo que deberias usar push.

O bien antes de enviar debes armar tu objeto que quieres enviar y luego lo envias por set

Comment: es verdad set borra todo e inserta, utilize update y con esa me guarda todos los datos.

Comment: setValue sobreescribe el valor donde estes y updateChildren con un hashmap lo cambia, para crear mas valores usas push que crea nuevas claves